# Using a method to add an object to a class

Tags: java, object, random, arraylist

This feels like a very obvious question but I can't figure out how to do it. I have a class called Hive and I want to add a hive object to my Garden class using an addHive method. I know it is going to be something very simple but I can't figure it out =/

My Garden class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Garden {

    ArrayList<Flower> flowerbed = new ArrayList<Flower>();
    Hive hive = null;

    public void anotherDay(){
        int size = flowerbed.size();

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Flower flower = flowerbed.get(i);
            flower.grow();
        }
    }

    public void addHive(Hive hive){

    }


    public void addFlower(Flower flower){
        flowerbed.add(flower);
    }


    public Flower getFlower(int fi){
        if(fi < flowerbed.size()){
            return flowerbed.get(fi);
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Integer getRandomInteger(Integer max)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int number;
        number = rand.nextInt(max) + 1;
        return new Integer(number);
    }   

    public Flower findFlower(){
        return getFlower(getRandomInteger(flowerbed.size()));
    }


    public int size(){
        return flowerbed.size();
    }   
}
```

I have also used what I feel is a rather untidy roundabout method for getting a random flower from my arraylist of flowers- can anyone suggest a better method or is this as good as it gets?

Comment: You have a `Hive` field. What are you going to do with it?

Comment: You may want a List<Hive> similar to your one for flowers...

Comment: yeah I think I'll do that- any suggestions on a better method of getting a random flower from the arraylist than the one I have done? it looks very messy to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need only one hive, use:

```
public void setHive(Hive hive){
    this.hive = hive;
}
```

If you need multiple hive, do exact the same as with flower. Including creating the list.

```
ArrayList<Hive> hives = new ArrayList<Hive>();


public void addHive(Hive hive){
    hives.add(hive);
}
```

Comment: Only call it setHive.